# Advice on Template String Loop with Buttons

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button, innerhtml

I am currently working on a mini web application and would like some advice. I know the reason for my issue and I know one way to get around it but it would mean undoing a lot of the work that I have already done.

The issue I have is I am currently using a template string inside a for loop to print data and I have a delete button with a listener. Currently it is only working for the last button the in the list and I know it is because I am destroying the innerHTML every time I use html = x.

What I would like to know is....is there an easy way around this or should I just use append child etc instead?

```
        for(let prod of products){
           console.log("Doc ID",doc.id);

        const li1 = `
            <p><div>${prod.name} <div class="right"><font class=pink-text>Location:</font> $${prod.location}  <button data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}" class="btn-remove">Delete</button></div></div></p>
        `;
        html += li1;

        } //end for loop




        const li2 = `
            <br />
            <button class="btn blue darken-2 z-depth-0 right modal-trigger" data-target="modal-prodedit">Add/Edit Attributes</button><br />
            </div>
            </li>
        `;
        html += li2;                    

        productList.innerHTML = html;


        const removeBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}"]`);
        console.log("removeBTN",removeBtn);
        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
            console.log(`deleted row ${e.target.dataset.removeButtonId}`);
          });
```

Comment: Yes, you probably should use DOM methods instead of `innerHTML`, but still your approach could work if you simply installed the handler on *all* buttons, not only a single one? Use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Where does `doc.id` come from?

Comment: Well I am using Firestore database so that is where the doc.id comes in
`code`
  doc.ref.collection("vendors").get().then((Snapshot) => {
      const vendors = Snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

   console.log(doc.id, '=>', vendors);


I will try the querySelectorAll and see how that works for me....if not I will use the DOM methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using querySelector() method which returns the first element it finds.  If you want to attach that listener to all rows you need to use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).  You'll need to differentiate between which row was selected, which doesn't seem to be in your DOM model.  So I'd add a `data-product-id` attribute to your button, and the listener can use that to know which product was deleted.

Comment: would I still need the data-product-id even though I already have a data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}"   ?

Comment: Yes.  As far as I could tell from your example doc.id doesn't change per row.  It's the same value across all rows so clicking remove on row 1 vs row 2 the listener wouldn't do anything different if it only worked with doc.id.  That's why I reasoned you would need product.id within the delete button listener. to make it do something different per row.

Comment: ahhh ok. yes doc.id is returned as a different value for each row from the Firestore database. So as the for of loop executes for each product in the database, it will return the unique id that is assigned in the database. I also confirmed this in my console.log output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help with this one.

The SelectAll worked to some extent but I decided to redo my code from scratch using DOM elements to appendChild. Once done, this made everything sooooo much easier. Decided to change it to give myself more flexibility with the code.